# How to always run php in console interactively way not to exit?

Tags: php-5.3

I am in debian7.8+php5.3 .

```
root@debian:/home/debian# php -a
Interactive mode enabled

<?php
echo  "hello";
?>
```

No reaction when to click enter ,to click ctrl+D can get the output:

```
 hello
```

But it will exit from php Interactive mode  into debian console.

```
root@debian:/home/debian#
```

How to always run php in console interactively way  not to exit ?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install php5-readline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use phpsh - An interactive shell for php

How to install phpsh

```
$ sudo apt-get install python # this is necessary to run phpsh
$ cd ~/

$ wget https://github.com/facebook/phpsh/zipball/master
$ unzip phpsh-master.zip

$ cd phpsh-master
$ sudo cp -r src /etc/phpsh # phpsh seems to complain unless it resides at /etc/phpsh
$ sudo ln -s /etc/phpsh/phpsh /usr/bin/phpsh # put phpsh on the $PATH
```

Run phpsh

```
$ phpsh
Starting php
type 'h' or 'help' to see instructions & features
php> echo 'hello world';
hello world
php>
```